# How can I mount this .img file and browse its contents?

Tags: debian, mount, fdisk

I am interested in mounting a firmware image and browsing its contents. I attempted this with the `mount` command but received some errors ("you must specify filesystem type"). However I think there may be other issues here. I believe the below information should be all that I need to accomplish this, I'm just not sure what to do with this information.

How can I mount this .img file and browse its contents?

Running `file`

```
/root/Downloads/FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.img: u-boot legacy uImage, Linux-3.2.40, Linux/ARM, OS Kernel Image (Not compressed), 3856080 bytes, Thu Nov 20 13:45:36 2014, Load Address: 0x00008000, Entry Point: 0x00008000, Header CRC: 0x5CAE7F84, Data CRC: 0xFCF78543
```

Running `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /root/Downloads/FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.img: 26 MB, 26345472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3 cylinders, total 51456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x80811005

Disk /root/Downloads/FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.img doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: What mount command did you try exactly?

Comment: can you show the full mount command you tried, arguments, options, and all?

Comment: @Skaperen This isn't a filesystem image (it's possibly the concatenation of a kernel image and filesystem image), so `mount` alone isn't enough anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The first 3856080 bytes of this file is a kernel image. After that, there is a filesystem image. The filesystem is at offset 3932160 (3856080 rounded up to the next multiple of 128kB); I found it by inspection, I don't know where the information is stored in the image (it may be related to the erase size on the intended device). The filesystem is [JFFS2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFFS2), which is common on such devices.

JFFS2 filesystems cannot be mounted directly on Linux, because the filesystem driver requires the filesystem to be on top of an [MTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_Technology_Device) device. You can [use a fake MTD device in RAM](http://wiki.emacinc.com/wiki/Mounting_JFFS2_Images_on_a_Linux_PC#Mounting_JFFS2_Images_using_RAM) to work around this limitation. You need to extract the JFFS2 image from the boot image; it has to be an integer number of erase blocks. In a nutshell:

```
modprobe mtdram total_size=32768 erase_size=128
modprobe mtdblock
<FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.img tail -c +3932161 | head -c 22413312 >/dev/mtdblock0
mount -t jffs2 /dev/mtdblock0 /mnt
```

Alternatively, you can use the programs `jffs2dump` and `jffs2reader` from the [MTD utilities](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/).

```
<FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.img tail -c +3932161 | head -c 22413312 >|FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.jffs2
jffs2reader FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.jffs2 >FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.contents
jffs2reader FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.jffs2 -d /
jffs2reader FW_WRT1900AC_1.1.8.164461_prod.jffs2 -f /etc/version
```

Comment: Can I still read it if the image is bigger than my RAM size?

Comment: @Alex With `jffs2reader` it doesn't matter. With `mdtram` the image does need to fit in RAM.